# Convert data from data.table to matrix efficiently (speed and memory)

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I have a ~20,000x20,000 data, how do i convert the from `data.table()` to a `matrix` efficiently in terms of speed and memory?

I tried `m = as.matrix(dt)` but it takes very long with many warnings. `df = data.frame(dt)` takes very long and result in reaching memory limits as well.

Is there any efficient way to do this? Or, simply a function in data.table which returns `dt` as as matrix form(as required to feed into a statistical model using the `glmnet` package)?

Simply wrapping into as.matrix gives me below error:

```
x = as.matrix(dt)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) : Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
  2: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) : Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
  3: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) : Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
  4: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) : Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

**My OS:** I have 64 bit Windows7 and 8gb ram, my Windows task manager shows Rgui.exe taking up spaces more than 4gb before and were still fine though.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you give a taste of what your data looks like (use `dput(subsetofyourdata)`)?  What were the warnings you saw when you tried `as.matrix`?

Comment: can you put the structure of your table in the question?

Comment: i'd double check that your computer isn't going to explode by feeding it a 20k by 20k matrix first...me thinks that will likely be the case if you don't have the  memory hanging around to convert to `as.matrix()`. You can give this a whirl some random data like so `matrix(runif(20000*20000),ncol = 20000)`. On my machine, this takes up about 3GB worth of space...so is not a svelte chunk of data by any means.

Comment: @Justin
> x=as.matrix(dt)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.9 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In unlist(X, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 8131Mb: see help(memory.size)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis
dt contains 1 character column (key)
and integers for the rest.

Comment: @Chase
I have 64bit windows 7 and 8gb ram, my windows task manager shows Rgui.exe taking up spaces more than 4gb before and were still fine though.

Comment: @GibsonGay - the error message above indicates you're running out of memory. General rule of thumb re: memory management is that you need 3x available memory for any given object you're trying to operate on. `data.table()` relaxes some of those criteria due to it's awesomeness - but you're trying to go away from `data.table()`. In my experience, the modeling functions require more than 3x memory on occasion but i have no experience with `glmnet()`. Unless you have another stick of memory hanging around, I think you're better off figure out Amazon EC2 and launching this in the cloud.

Comment: See [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/) for making Amazon EC2 trivially easy to use.

Comment: @Chase Thanks alot, I agree data.table is super awesome. I have made an error on my part to include the character column into the matrix, which elevated the matrix's class to character for all columns. removing this column allowed a integer matrix to be made and it converted successfully without errors/warnings and ran the model fine.:) 

Thank you for all your help though, I will certainly keep Amazon EC2 in mind!

Comment: @GibsonGay Thanks for the update. I was starting to worry there for a second. Could you self answer, and self accept, to wrap up please.

Comment: @GibsonGay Self-answer neatly please...

Comment: @MattDowle moved the OP's resolution to wiki answer. OP is offline since 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    result <- as.matrix(tidytext::cast_sparse(dat_table,
    column_name_of_rows,
    column_name_of_columns,
    column_name_of_values))
```

It should be very efficient and fast.

Answer (score 2):

@GibsonGay:

> I have made an error on my part to include the character column into the matrix, which elevated the matrix's class to character for all columns. Removing this column allowed a integer matrix to be made and it converted successfully without errors/warnings and ran the model fine.